# How do I get the multiple result in a query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a query ... I'm using entity framework in the project.
The query below is working

```
public async Task<dynamic> CriarResumo(Pedido pedido)
            {
                var query = (from p in context.Pedido
                             join pi in context.PedidoItem on p.Id equals pi.PedidoId
                             join t in context.Tamanho on pi.TamanhoId equals t.Id
                             join s in context.Sabor on pi.SaborId equals s.Id
                             join pia in context.PedidoItemAdicional on pi.Id equals pia.PedidoItemId
                             join a in context.Adicional on pia.AdicionalId equals a.Id
                             where p.Id == pedido.Id
                             select new
                             {
                                 tamanho = t.Descricao + " - " + t.ML+"ml",
                                 sabor = s.Descricao,
                                 adicionais = a.Descricao,
                                 tempoPreparo = p.TempoTotal,
                                 valorTotal = p.ValorTotal
                             });

                var o = query.FirstOrDefault();

                return o;
            }
```

"Adicional" is an associative table (PedidoItemId and AdicionalId) so it is possible that the search returns more than one result.

Ex: PedidoItem Id = 67

[image]

The Item has the Adicional->id 1 and the Adicional->id 2.

The way I'm doing I can only get the Adicional in id 1. How can I solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `.FirstOrDefault()` which returns first element of a sequence or a default value if no item is found. If you want to return a collection of items you should use a method that returns it: e.g. `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`